# JQuery File Upload middleware - Image versions not creating

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, jquery-file-upload

I have my `jquery-file-upload-middleware` configured as described in simple [usage example](https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware#jquery-file-upload-middleware):

```
// configure upload middleware
    upload.configure({
        uploadDir: './public/uploads',
        uploadUrl: '/uploads',
        imageVersions: {
            thumbs: {
                width: 80,
                height: 80
            }
        }
    });
```

Image uploads successfully, folder *thumbs* is created but there is **no files** inside. I tried adding other image versions but problem remains.

Using *jquery-file-upload-middleware v0.1.5, node v4.1.0 and express v4.13.3*.

Am I missing some additional settings?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things that could be wrong

**1) You can't write to your temp (tmp) directory**

You don't specify a `tmpDir` in your config, so it's looking for `/tmp`
You can specify one such as `tmpDir : __dirname + '/public/tmp',`

So your config becomes

```
upload.configure({
    tmpDir : __dirname + '/public/tmp',
    uploadDir: './public/uploads',
    //etc...
});
```

**2) You need to ensure `ImageMagick` is installed**

See this issue for more info https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware/issues/34

You can download ImageMagick binaries from here
[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

**EDIT**

Need to add some logging.
See here
https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware

Add this:

```
    upload.on('error', function (e, req, res) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
```

... this should tell you (by outputting to console) if there's any errors.

Comment: Are there any additional configuration needed after installing ImageMagick? I installed it on my machine but didn't solve problem...

Comment: i'd configure some logging - see here under "More sophisticated example - Events" - output the logs to the console and see if anything is going wrong....

Comment: Could you please update your comment as I don't see that link with example?

Comment: Thanks! Both things were missing on my machine. Upvote for question will be appreciated